# Como eliminar varios ID de mi base de datos, laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5, migration

Mi error es el siguiente

```
public function store(EmpleadosStoreRequest $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());

        $user= new User();
        $user->name=$request->nombres;
        $user->email=$request->email;
        $user->password=bcrypt($request->cedula);
        $user->save();

        $empleado= new Empleados();
        $empleado->nombres=$request->nombres;
        $empleado->apellidos=$request->apellidos;
        $empleado->cedula=$request->cedula;
        $empleado->email=$request->email;
        $empleado->cel=$request->cel;
        $empleado->local=$request->local;
        $empleado->direccion=$request->direccion;
        $empleado->id_usuario=$user->id;
        $empleado->id_categoria=$request->id_categoria;
        $empleado->save();
```

En la funcion `store` se crea un empleado y un usuario, cada uno en su tabla en la BDD, con diferentes valores pero que trabajan con ids obviamente, el problema esta en que cuando elimino en la vista el empleado, elimina el empleado pero no elimina el usuario en la tabla users, solamente el empleado en la tabla empleados.
Entonces quisiera saber que hacer para que cuando elimine el empleado, tambien elimine el usuario registrado con esa id.

Esta es la `migración`

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombres');
            $table->string('apellidos');
            $table->string('nacionalidad');
            $table->integer('cedula')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('cel')->nullable();
            $table->string('local')->nullable();
            $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_categoria');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_usuario');



            $table->foreign('id_usuario')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

y tambien ubico la función `destroy` del controlador

```
public function destroy($id_empleado)
    { 

        $empleado=Empleados::find($id_empleado);
        $empleado->delete();
        return back()->with('eliminar' , 'El empleado ha sido eliminado correctamente');
}
```

Comment: y pq la funcion que destruye el empleado no destruye el usuario?

Comment: He intentado hacerlo, pero no logro que funcione, me da mil errores que no consigue las variables, si sabes como poder hacer, seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: podes mostrar lo que intentaste y que errores te dio?

Comment: Bueno, parecido a lo que esta en la funcion destroy, en vez de $empleado, intente hacer una con $user->que encontrara el id_usuario, y eso, ->delete(); pero no funciono.

Comment: no funciono? que error tiro?

Comment: public function destroy($id_empleado, $id_usuario)
    { 

        $empleado=Empleados::find($id_empleado);
        $empleado->delete();
        $user=User::find($id_usuario);
        $user->delete();
        return back()->with('eliminar' , 'El empleado ha sido eliminado correctamente');
} Lo tengo asi tal cual, y en realidad el elimina, pero no elimina el usuario que crea, elimina el empleado pero no el usuario, no hace nada.

Comment: amigo la base de datos y asegurate que la llave foranea esta  configurada como cascade, ten en cuenta que esto aplica para todas las tablas donde tengas referenciado el usuario si una de ellas no esta como cascade probablemente te da error ya que no permite eliminar el usuario. De acuerto a estas dos tablas usuario y empleado no deberias tener problemas en eliminar el usuario y la base de datos en automatico elimina los empleados que tengan la referencia del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que borrarlo antes, y asegurarte que no de un error entre medias de la operación. (El orden es importante)

```
public function destroy($id_empleado)
{ 
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

        $empleado=Empleados::find($id_empleado);
        User::find($empleado->id_usuario)->delete();
        $empleado->delete();

        DB::commit();
        return back()->with('eliminar' , 'El empleado ha sido eliminado correctamente');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return back()->with('eliminar' , 'Error al eliminar empleado');

    }
```

}